# I want the image and text together horizontal, the picture is above the text, in RecycleView and CardView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want my view like this where image and text are sides by side but it is showing text below the image:

[[image: This type of format I want]]

but it is showing like this where the picture is above the text, I have checked my code but I am able to get the error is where :

[[image: This type I am getting]]

my code for hindu_design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:scaleX="0.5"
                android:scaleY="0.9"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/fruits" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#00F85C2C"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                android:text="@string/todo"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

my code for activity_hindu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".fragments.ShopFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shop_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:background="@drawable/headingbg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hindu"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            tools:listitem="@layout/hindu_design" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try without a card view? That's a weird behavior from the LinearLayout.

Comment: You can do it by using `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in hindu_design layout

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/playerImage"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"

            android:src="@drawable/search"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">




            <TextView

                android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                android:text="Sylhet Students Association"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingLeft="77dp"
                android:paddingTop="22dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:typeface="serif"/>

            </RelativeLayout>   
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

before do any things please use **ConstraintLayout** instead of **LinearLayout** or **RelativeLayout**

and for this sample item you can try like this

it`s for **item.xml**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and it`s for **main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Header"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textHeader" /> 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```